# Use jax ws client native library instead of jboss cxf library

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, jax-ws

I have a Client Web Service that invoke a SOAP service. It works fine when I run it as Java Application, but when it is deployed I receive some exceptions caused by cxf library that jboss (v7.1.1) has imported by default. Is there a method to exclude them?

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more details ? Like sharing screenshots or the actual error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the webservice subsystem in JBoss standalone-*.xml.

Comment: subsytem exclusion works with v7.1.2 but v7.1.1 does not support this method, unfortunatelly. Is there any solution for v7.1.1?